# Spring parsing JSON RequestBody: "Could not resolve type id" or "Root name does not match expected"

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-rest

I'm building a REST API with Spring; well currently I'm failing to do so.

## TL;DR

I get either this (error 1)

> JSON parse error: Could not resolve type id 'test1' as a subtype of `crm.zappes.core.template.domain.model.TemplateRequest`: known type ids = [TemplateRequest]

or this (error 2)

> JSON parse error: Root name ('test1') does not match expected ('TemplateRequest') for type `crm.zappes.core.template.domain.model.TemplateRequest`

## Model

I used `@JsonTypeInfo` to wrap the class name around it; that leads to error 1.

```
{"TemplateRequest":{"test1":"Anakin","test2":"Skywalker"}}
```

If I use the default without this annotation the generated JSON doesn't have a wrapping root element which leads to error 2:

```
{"test1":"Anakin","test2":"Skywalker"}
```

```
@Data @Builder @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
// With this I get error 1, without it error 2
@JsonTypeInfo(include = JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT, use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME)
public class TemplateRequest {
    private String test1;
    private String test2;
}
```

## Controller

In this Controller Endpoint I want the JSON to be converted into a `TemplateRequest` Model Object.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/zappes/")
public class TemplateController {
    @PostMapping(value = "/template/test", consumes = {MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE})
    public ResponseEntity<String> testPost(@RequestBody TemplateRequest request) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Hello World");
    }
}
```

If I change it to `@RequestBody String request` it works fine and I see the 2 JSON variants (see above), so the endpoint mapping itself works. Spring just cannot parse the JSON into a model object. Which is kind of weird, because the JSON was also generated by the Spring REST framework. See next section.

## Test

Here I'm sending the POST Call to the Controller.

```
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.DEFINED_PORT)
class TemplateControllerIntegrationTests {
    @Test
    void testPost() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth("server_user", "server_password");

        var request = TemplateRequest.builder().test1("Anakin").test2("Skywalker").build();

        var requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(request, headers);

        var restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        var result = restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8083/zappes/template/test", HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, String.class);

        Assertions.assertEquals("Hallo Welt", result.getBody());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently there is no default JSON Converter to I needed to create a little Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter mappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter() {
    var jsonConverter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
    var objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    jsonConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
    return jsonConverter;
}
```